# Is it possible to use POE (Power Over Ethernet) so that my wifi router can work with out power?

Tags: wireless-networking, power-supply

We are living in a location where we have frequent power cuts.
But I want my wifi router to work with out power.
Is there any way that I can use POE to achieve what i want.
So that I can use internet even there is a power out.

Comment: The power doesn’t just magically appear. It still has to come from somewhere. So you’ll still need a UPS.

Comment: If you have a power cut where do you think the power over Ethernet will come from?

Comment: Short answer: No

Comment: To achieve this you need a switch which supports POE. If the switch turned off then your wifi router will also be turned off, So you must provide uninterrupted power supply to your POE switch.

Comment: You could possibly use a 3G dongle, depending on far the nearest tower is, and if the power is also off there...

Comment: POE is a means of distributing power. But what is to be the source of that power? That is the key question.

Comment: Obligatory http://dilbert.com/strip/1994-09-25 .

Answer (score 3):

No. While POE uses ethernet cabling as a power source, you'd still need power from somewhere - either from a switch that acts as a [PSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_over_Ethernet#Power_sourcing_equipment) or an injector, which in turn need power from somewhere. POE switches are typically large high power devices, and injectors typically run off mains or at least *unusual* higher voltages.

The solution to your problem might be to find a wifi router that runs over USB/5V or 12V and have some off grid source powering it.

For USB, you could use a suitable power bank (one that would allow passthrough when its charging) as a poor man's ups.

12V solar is pretty common and there's commercially available kits with a UPS battery, charging equipment and such. You'd be able to power *small* appliances like a router or maybe even a modem. The trick here would be to work out how big a power supply you'd need/want within a budget. You might even be able to do POE injection off such a setup, but that's out of your scope.

Essentially, you need *some* power, be it a large array of hamsters, an intern on a bike or solar, for *Power* to be able to go *Over Ethernet*. You can't get the power out of nowhere.

Comment: While you greatly answer the question, I'd still add something: wifi router is just the last part of the chain, there can be other devices e.g. modem which still need electricity. Not mentioning ISP, if the outage covers a wider area (which seems to be the case) then it likely will affect ISP too, so having electricity for the own devices won't help.

Comment: totally. Feels like a modern smartphone might be the *actual* solution here